# Python - Change Desktop Background Fast

Tags: python, windows, performance, background, ctypes

I was wondering if there was any way to - in Python - change the desktop background of a Windows 7 machine quickly. Right now I'm using:

```
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(20, 0, picture_path, 0)
```

And while this works, it's not very fast. I was wondering if there was some way to get the background to update in less than a second.

Thanks!

Edit -- It's probably worth noting that my goal it to change the background very fast between many known images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how to work with PowerShell, you could try making a PowerShell function to change the background image (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproui/thread/72a9b4bf-071b-47cd-877d-0c0629a9eb90):

```
Function Set-WallPaper($Value)
{
 Set-ItemProperty -path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop\' -name wallpaper -value $value
 rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
}
```

and then call the PowerShell function from python:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen([r'path/to/PowerShell/script.exe',
                         '-ExecutionPolicy',
                         'Unrestricted',
                         'path/to/background_image.png'], cwd=os.getcwd())
```

Comment: I didn't need to use Powershell, simply introducing the background change as a different python file and using subprocess to run it in the background worked! Thanks!

Comment: @user1019250: Did you use `_winreg` to modify the registry? When you exit you can call `SystemParametersInfoA` via ctypes to update with the final image in the user profile, if that matters.

Comment: @PhilipMassey: I know this thread is a bit dusty. But I'm trying to solve the same problem and would really like to know your implementation if you can remember. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/abody/Glee-wallpaper).
They use bitmaps only but there are functions to convert images like shown [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/180801-convert-image-format/).

Comment: My problem is that SystemParametersInfoA doesn't update the background fast enough - if I try to update the picture every second (even if the picture is already saved and I know the path) there is a (farely significant) lag. I don't immediately see how this fixes that problem.